# deploy solution to azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

i have a .net solution, with a Mvc 4.5 web, a c# server dll, another webservice layer dll, etc.
I want to deploy it on a azure virtual machine xx.cloudapp.net:8080

There are many guids on how to deploy a new website on azure, but since this solutions contains a lot of dlls, i need a virtual machine.
I didnt found any guide on how to do it, can you please give me a link or something?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* use Virtual Machines to install DLLs - you can do this with Cloud Services (web/worker role) as well, via startup tasks. As long as these DLLs are easy to fetch (e.g. blob storage) and quick to install, you can take that route. Many do just that, since this allows you to work with stateless OS VMs (where you don't worry about maintaining the OS, or making copies of a VM when wanting to scale out to multiple instances).

That said: To install to a Virtual Machine, you'd typically copy files to your VM somehow (maybe fetching from a CI engine, possibly ftp'ing the files, whatever procedure you'd typically use with a Windows server). And you'd use RDP for gaining access to the desktop.

Once you have the VM set up just how you want it, you can then create an *image* of the VM and add it to your personal gallery, whereby you can then spin up additional VMs based on that image. Unlike Cloud Services, each Virtual Machine will then take on a life of its own (and live in its own VHD in its own blob), where you'd have to distribute both OS updates and app updates to each VM as the need arises.

Comment: Yes, Cloud Services allow install DLLS.

Comment: However, i need to run a service watchdog and a few webservices, so i need a VM. Thanks for your comment, finally i have finished the deploy :D